# CaLayer performance with animating pie chart

Tags: ios, performance, calayer

I've developed a Pie Chart with animating pie segments. Each segment s a sublayer with custom drawing. The start and end angles are dynamic properties. The parts and their labels are drawn with core gaphics.

However, i notice bad performance with lots of red layers in the simulator. I cannot you opaque layers with pie parts obviously. i've set the ShouldRasterize to yes, that helped a bit. I also tried using `instruments` to spot the problem to no avail.

Comment: Post your code. There's no way we can guess what's causing performance issues in your code if we can't see it.

Comment: I'll be attaching code soon, but for now i can say that disabling `shouldRasterize` made a huge improvement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve the problem, so i took a totally different approach by using smaller layers.

Answer (score 0):

[Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/framework/Source/CPTPieChart.h)

This open-source project may bring some thoughts about perfomance.
I've used this with animations in production and have great results

Comment: I will certainly look at it